# Create vector based on condition applied on another vector

Tags: arrays, excel, matlab, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am very new to Matlab. This seems like a simple thing to do and Im sure its my lack of experience, so apologies in advance.

Basically, I want to use information from two rows to overwrite data in another.

I have two rows of data output e.g:

```
B = [1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4]
C = [0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0]
```

Then I set up new rows D and E which will be used for the new rule based output:

```
D=nan(1,8);
E=nan(1,8);
```

I want to overwrite the cells of D/E that correspond to values of B with those in C:

Eg for B = 1 I want to get:

```
D= [0 nan nan nan 0 nan nan nan]
```

And for B = 3 I want:

```
E= [nan nan 1 nan nan nan 1 nan]
```

My current attempt is this (but it doesnt work):

```
for D= 1:8
if B(n) == 1;
 D(n)=C(n);
elseif B(n) == 3;
 E(n)=C(n);
end
end
```

N.B If I were doing this in excel I would use this to create D (copied down all the rows):

```
D1=IF(B1=1,C1,"nan")
```

Any help at all would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's as easy as that:

your vectors:

```
B = [1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4]
C = [0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0]
D = NaN(1,8)
E = NaN(1,8)
```

then apply:

```
D(B==1) = C(B==1)
E(B==3) = C(B==3)
```

and you get:

```
D =    0   NaN   NaN   NaN     0   NaN   NaN   NaN


E =  NaN   NaN     1   NaN   NaN   NaN     1   NaN
```

Comment: You, my friend, are a life saver!

Answer (score 2):

While I would advise you to use @thewaywewalk's answer, your initial solution was almost correct. The only error was that you used the wrong loop variable `D` instead of `n`. So this works nicely:

```
B = [1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4];
C = [0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0];

D = nan(1,8);
E = nan(1,8);

for n = 1:8
    if B(n) == 1
        D(n) = C(n);
    elseif B(n) == 3
        E(n) = C(n);
    end
end
```

In general, in Matlab you should avoid looping through a vector like this. Usually there are ways that are much faster than using a loop statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
D = nan(size(B));
enter code here
D(B==1) = 0;
E(B==3) = 1;
```

The expression `B==1` is interpreted as a logical array.